# function as argument vs handler JS

Tags: event-handling

I'm learning JS and JQuery. And I was wondering why this code return 9 on window load?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function foo(a){
        console.log(a *= a);
    };
    $('#btn').click(foo(3));
});
```

Why it doesn't do the same as a standard handler?

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    foo(3);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's actually happening here is that you have two different cases:

Imagine, or actually open up your browser's console and paste these snippets in.

Okay, so if instead of `$(elem).click`, you had the following function:

```
function bar(){
    console.log(parameters);
}
```

<sub>`parameters` is a keyword that prints all parameters passed to the function.</sub>

And additionally, imagine `foo` looked like this:

```
function foo(a){
    return a * a;
};
```

<sub>The `=` operator is unnecessary as the `a` is discarded immediately anyway.</sub>

Now, if I called the `bar` function like:

```
bar(foo(3));
```

`bar` would return `9`.

Because `foo` is getting executed before it gets passed to `bar`.

Whereas in, the following:

```
bar(function(){
    foo(3);
});
```

You would find that `bar` would return `function(){foo(3)}`, because it's not being executed in the parameters, instead that is passing the function reference, whereas `foo(3)` passes the function result.

So say if you wanted it to print 9 in the console on the button you could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function foo(a){
        console.log(a *= a);
    };
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        foo(3);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok. I've understood that in my case I pass value to the .click, not a function.  But I still can't realize why .click appears on window.load?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by '.click appears on window.load'. Could you expand that a little more so I can help you

Comment: I expected to see 9 in the console when I click on the  button.